# Passing **float array from C++ Dll to python

Tags: python, c++, pointers, dll, ctypes

I am currently working with C/C++ functions imported into python thanks to a Dll and ctypes. In the DLL, I have a function that takes a float **variable as argument. This argument is filled in the function and I get it back on python using ctypes.

I have a solution which works using 2 for loops, but this is very slow when the 2D array has a lot of points.

Do you know a way to do without these for loops?

Here is my code :

*Short version of the exported function (DLL)*

```
unsigned short ClassExample::GetData(float **Samples)
{
    for(long i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if(ch < NB_ROWS_MAX) 
            {
                Samples[ch]][i] = this->Data[ch][i];
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
        } ...
```

*Python code*

```
def GetSamples(self, ROWS, COLUMN):

    Data = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) * ROWS)()
    for i in range(COLUMN):
        Data[i] = (ctypes.c_float * COLUMN)()

    try:
        succeed = lib._PyGetData(ClassExampleObj, ctypes.byref(Data))
        if succeed != 0:
            print("Error number :", succeed)
    except:
        print("Unknown Error")

    Data_np = numpy.zeros((ROWS, COLUMN), dtype=float)
    for i in range(ROWS):
        for j in range(COLUMN):
            Data_np[i, j] = float(Data[i][j])
    return Data_np
```

Thank you !

Comment: If I understand you right, you ask how to make the code more efficient?

Comment: Exactly ! I am beginner with ctypes and dll so I'm not entirely comfortable with that

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is efficiency then you probably are working with very very large datasets.

The easiest way to make a 2-d matrix iteration much faster is to make it 1-d. If you have X columns and Y rows, then instead of accessing `matrix[I][j]` you can access `matrix[i*X+j]`, which saves you a dereference, and possibly many cache-misses. If possible, you could even go further and treat the matrix as a 1-d array.

Another time-saving solution is to avoid conditions as much as possible. If you only have conditions inside the for-loop, the compiler will be able to greatly optimize it.

Without seeing more of your code it is hard to tell whether you have an inefficient code or simply handling too much data for your computer, but the guidelines I gave seem to fit from the example you gave.

The last thing I want to mention is that `float` is quite imprecise and you better use `double` if possible.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'll try to optimize this way.

Comment: Also use numpy, which can build and transfer arrays to ctypes without the data copy you are doing in the for loops.

Comment: I didn't know this, thanks you very much. I will check that.